# Unable to parse simple command line with commandlineparser

Tags: c#, command-line-parser

I have to parse an imposed command line which mix single/double dash args, args with `=` or   as separator,etc (not very proper....)

The command line is like `myexe.exe -Url=https://blabla.com/ --TestValue=val1 -monoapp -Ctx "default ctx"  Open -Test2=CO0ZJP6f-ca`

I'm trying to do that with [commandlineparser](https://github.com/commandlineparser/commandline).
(I suppose it's able to manage that, right ? )

So first I'm trying to parse the first parameter (`myexe.exe -Url=https://blabla.com/`).

```
public class CommandLineOptions
{
   [Option("Url", Required = true)]
   public string Url { get; set; }
}

....... In another file but in the  same  assembly

static void Main(string[] args) // args[0] = "-Url=https://blabla.com/" 
{

   var commandLineOptions = new CommandLineOptions();


   var parseResult = Parser.Default.ParseArguments<CommandLineOptions>(args).WithParsed(result => commandLineOptions = result);

   System.Console.WriteLine(parseResult.Tag); //NotParsed
   System.Console.WriteLine(commandLineOptions.Url);
}
```

With that code, I have 2 errors `CommandLine.MissingRequiredOptionError` and `CommandLine.UnknownOptionError`.

(The `MissingRequiredOptionError` is produced beacause it cannot find the Url parameter)

So do you know where is my mistake ?

Thanks in advance for your help ;)

Answer (score 0):

So final dev from `commandlineparser` said it isn't possible to parse it.
A single line option must be one char option.
The only way to bypass that is to preprocess the arguments.

I did this, it's working but it not allow short option composition (like in `tar -xvf` for example)

```
args = args.Select(arg => Regex.IsMatch(arg, "^-\\w{2,}") ? "-" + arg : arg ).ToArray();
```